# Print HTML page on mobile upon user click

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, mobile

I want to print/take screenshot of my whole HTML page, which is a widget for a mobile app and its programmed on an online platform (cant call external code links).

The code is pretty normal, like this:

```html
    <div id="PO">
  
    <table>
    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#2AD2C9"><h2>Purchase Order</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#97D700"><h3>Equipment</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"></td>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><b><em>Tipo/Quantity</em></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Plaque model:</td>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><select id="tipoPlaca" size="1">
        <option id="defaultP" value="0">Select a plaque</option>
         
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">Longitud PVC:</td>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#F4F4F4"><input type="number" id="longitudPVC" onchange="calculoCableria()" size="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Arrangements:</td>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><input type="number" id="arrangements" onchange="espacioArreglos()" size="1"></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Plaques:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFF00"><div id="container"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Then there are JS functions that trigger upon changing the value of some inputs, but the only thing I want is that on the end of using it, I am able to click a button and something like a new window would pop up with exactly the same image that you see after filling what necessary. Already tried many different approaches, all of them were found here in StackOverflow, but I never found a solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing happens.... I don't think I can use those commands like window.print or .open in a mobile